# How to use 'SUM' to calculate amount1 and amount2?

Tags: linq

How to use 'SUM' to calculate amount1 and amount2 that is in my result, sum2?

```
 var sum2 = (from p in db.tbl_relacijes  
           select p);  

 Button12.Text = (sum2.Sum());
```

Comment: Your question is way too vague. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that relacijes has two columns for amount1 and amount2

```
Button12.Text=sum2.Sum(a=>a.amount1 + a.amount2).ToString();
```

Comment: Snap! Almost word for word, +1 for correct answer and fastest fingers :)

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to be sure what you're asking, assuming amount1 and amount2 columns in the table?

```
Button12.Text = sum2.Sum(row => row.amount1 + row.amount2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I must say I don't really get the question, but maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
var sum2 = (from p in db.tbl_relacijes  
           select p);  

 Button12.Text = (sum2.Sum(t => t.amount1 + t.amount2)).ToString();
```

Comment: The result of `(sum2.Sum(t => t.amount1 + t.amount2))` isn't likely to be a string.